# what does this jquery $('.some-class',$('#some-id')) mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, syntax, jquery-selectors

i know the meaning of `$('.some-class')` and `$('#some-id')`, but i do really not know the meaning of `$('.some-class',$('#some-id'))`, hoping some one can explain it for me, many thanks.

Comment: A confusing way of writing `$('#some-id .some-class')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `selector` with `context`, `some-class` will be looked up in element with in element with id `some-id`.

`'.some-class'` is selector  and `$('#some-id')` is context

The syntax in the jQuery documents for selector is `jQuery( selector [ , context ]  )` you can read more about selectors [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

*`Without context` $('.some-class') will bring all the elements in document with class some-class. `With context` $('.some-class', $('#some-id')) will bring all the elements with in element with id `some-id`.*

Answer (score 3):

The **second parameter is context**.

If you look at jQuery source you can see it as second parameter to $ or jQuery function.

**$('selector')** traverse the whole document

**$('selector',context)** traverse with in the given context/ element

A few line from jQuery library source

```
(function( window, undefined ) {

// Define a local copy of jQuery
var jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
        /// <summary>
        ///     1: $(expression, context) - This function accepts a string containing a CSS selector which is then used to match a set of elements.
        ///     2: $(html) - Create DOM elements on-the-fly from the provided String of raw HTML.
        ///     3: $(elements) - Wrap jQuery functionality around a single or multiple DOM Element(s).
        ///     4: $(callback) - A shorthand for $(document).ready().
        ///     5: $() - As of jQuery 1.4, if you pass no arguments in to the jQuery() method, an empty jQuery set will be returned.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="selector" type="String">
        ///     1: expression - An expression to search with.
        ///     2: html - A string of HTML to create on the fly.
        ///     3: elements - DOM element(s) to be encapsulated by a jQuery object.
        ///     4: callback - The function to execute when the DOM is ready.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="context" type="jQuery">
        ///     1: context - A DOM Element, Document or jQuery to use as context.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns type="jQuery" />

        // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
        return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

You search `.some-class` in `#some-id`.