# What does it mean like $("class","class")?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have seen a code which says `$("class1","class2")`.

If I execute `$("class1","class2")`, I get results in console, but if try `$("class2","class1")` I don't get any result. What does `$("class","class")` mean?

Comment: second argument is the context, `$("class1","class2")` ===> `$("class2 class1")`

Comment: Hope you have something here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13815037/what-does-this-jquery-some-class-some-id-mean

Comment: Essentially it's the same as `$('class2').find('class1')`. As the docs state _"Internally, selector context is implemented with the `.find()` method, so  `$( "span", this )` is equivalent to  `$( this ).find( "span" )`."_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context) you can find more.

1. The second parameter is called context (or parent selector).
2. Thus first parameter works as a selector, which is limited in the range of the second parameter. (Parameters may be `class/object/id`)
3. You may call or use it to select child element inside parent element.

You get result of `$('child_inside','parent')` but no result of `$('parent','child_inside')`.

Comment: It's faster then normal syntax selector

Answer (score 2):

can find the thing class1 inside class2 like this

```js
alert($(".class1",".class2").text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="class1">class1</p>
<p class="class2">class2</p>

<p class="class2"><span class="class1">class1(inside class2)</span></p>
```